# Using Context as parameter / argument

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the text of a button in the MenuScreen activity from the ChangeClass.

Looking up other answers on here I've found a solution that looks as if it may work:

```
public class ChangeClass{
    protected MenuScreen context;

    public ChangeClass(MenuScreen context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setupMenu(){
        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.btnMenuScreen0.setText("test 1");
            }
        });
    }
```

My problem is, I'm unsure how to refer to the Context as an argument when calling the method.

```
            ChangeClass changeClass = new ChangeClass (/*what goes here?*/);
            ChangeClass.setupMenu();
```

The class I ultimately want to access is the MenuScreen.class. How do I refer to that as a Context in an argument?

Comment: How about make a public method to change the text in MenuScreen, then call it whenever you want to change the text from other class or activity.

Comment: That's a functional work around until I figure out a better method. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: That's a simple work around, for a better solution you can use interface as callback to your Activity. The concept is still the same with your question.

Comment: The object instantiating ChangeClass must have a reference to MainScreen since ChangeClass requires a MenuScreen object.

Answer (score 0):

In `ChangeClass` just make the `context` an instance of the `Context` class.

```
public class ChangeClass{
    protected Context context;

    public ChangeClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    ...
```

Then when you create the new `ChangeClass`, do it like so

```
ChangeClass changeClass = new ChangeClass(MenuScreen.this);
```

Comment: `ChangeClass changeClass = new ChangeClass(MenuScreen.this);` is giving me an error that it's not an enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use

```
startActivityForResult(Intent, requestcode);
```

when calling the ChangeActivity then catch it on your MenuActivity using

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

[Here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example) is a sample on how to do it.

OR

You could just make your button a

```
public static Button btn;
```

Then on your ChangeActivity you could just

```
MenuActitivy.btn.setText("Hi");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried using the static method but for some reason I keep getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: No a static method. But a static variable. And i suspect that error is due to not initializing the button. Be sure you did

    btn = (Button) findviewById(R.id.button);

Comment: The button is initialized on the activity its actually used on. Do I need to initialize it on the activity calling the setText method?

Comment: Nope, you will just declare variable as `public static Button btn;` then just call `MenuActitivy.btn.setText("Hi");`. If it doesnt work please post some of your MenuActivity Button part codes and update your ChangeClass in the post to your current class so we will see how it is done